# Test will throw an error if i declare components as classes in davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Tags: reactjs, webpack, karma-runner

[The starterKit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit)

PhantomJS will throw :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.contextTypes')

My component is

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
    export default class InputText extends Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {}
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <input type="text" />
        )
    }
}
```

How can i test such components or how should i modify test-bundler.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'

export default class InputText extends Component<{}, {}> {
constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {}
}
render () {
    return (
        <input type="text" />
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are unit testing the component directly and are not referencing a component that is wired up using **connect()**.

I had the same error you described above when I realized that in my test I was referencing the component container that uses **connect()**.  Once I pointed it directly to the component itself, I stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred on a functional stateless component when I was exporting it as default at the bottom of the file.

Not working:

```
const GameBoard = ({ boardLength, xPos, yPos }) => {
....
}

export default GameBoard
```

Working:

```
export const GameBoard = ({ boardLength, xPos, yPos }) => {
....
}    
export default GameBoard
```

So I had to export the component itself as well as the `export default` at the bottom.